# Oracle How to get Execution Plan for SQL executed inside of PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, explain

Is it possible to examine the execution plan for a SQL statement executed inside a PLSQL block?

```
DECLARE
    l_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO l_count
    FROM foo;
END;
/
```

For regular SQL I would normally run the following to check the execution plan:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

However, this just reports:

```
NOTE: cannot fetch plan for SQL_ID: 3q0sujncq54wy, CHILD_NUMBER: 0
      Please verify value of SQL_ID and CHILD_NUMBER; 
      It could also be that the plan is no longer in cursor cache (check v$sql_plan)
```

Comment: If this is a test block, you can call dbms_xplan.display_cursor in a loop immediately after the SQL statement. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076322/230471

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look up the `sql_id` And `child_number` in `v$sql`. Something like:

```
Select s.sql_id, s.child_number
From   V$sql s
Where  upper(sql_text) like upper('SELECT COUNT(%FROM foo')
And    Sql_text not like '%v$sql%';
```

Note that pl/sql normalises static SQL for you to boost cursor sharing - it will be in upper case with much less white space.

Once you’ve got these, you can just input into the `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` function