# how to get explain plan from pl/sql function call?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql, oracle-sql-developer, explain

consider this working pl/sql block:

```
declare
    o_result       boolean;
    io_error       varchar2(30000);
    tab1           someTable1;
    tab2           someTable2;
begin
    tab1(1).col1 := 'str';
    tab1(1).col2 := 1;

    tab2(1).col1 := 'str';
    tab2(1).col2 := 0.5;
    tab2(1).col3 := 6;
    o_result := some_function(io_error, 2,'str', 5, to_date('01-JAN-23','DD-MON-YY'), to_date('31-DEC-23','DD-MON-YY'), 4, 'A', tab1, tab2, 'str', 'B', 'str');
end;
```

how to get the explain plan for pl/sql function calls where its inputs are dates and custom types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle How to get Execution Plan for SQL executed inside of PLSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312623/oracle-how-to-get-execution-plan-for-sql-executed-inside-of-plsql)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't because i want the execution plan for the PLSQL code, not SQL. since my function has in and out parameters, i cannot call it embedded in sql `select my_f(...) from dual`, i have to call it in pl/sql

Comment: There is no "execution plan for the PLSQL code"

Answer (score 0):

SQL and PL/SQL are different languages, different engines.
SQL is declarative and you can use explain plan, tuning advisor and other tools for this for SQL.
PL/SQL is imperative and the tool you're looking for is `DBMS_PROFILER`.

> DBMS_PROFILER
>
> The package provides an interface to profile existing PL/SQL
> applications and identify performance bottlenecks. You can then
> collect and persistently store the PL/SQL profiler data.

Comment: when i tried to run `exec dbms_profiler.start_profiler;` i got `Error executing PL/SQL profiler *Cause: An error occurred in during execution of a PL/SQL profiler procedure`. do you have any working example to be used in SQLDeveloper client?